# How to test a String thrown using Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I ran into a situation where a function throws a string.

I am aware that on jest we have the `toThrow` matcher that allows us to test that functions do in fact throw.
But this matcher is only working when what is thrown is an Error.

Is it possible to verify that a String is thrown using Jest?

The following code

```
async function funToTest(): Promise<number> {
  if (Math.random()) throw 'ERROR_CODE_X';
  return 10;
}

describe('funToTest', () => {
  it('should throw `ERROR_CODE_X`', () => {
    await expect(() => funToTest()).rejects.toThrow('ERROR_CODE_X');
  });
});
```

returns

```
funToTest › should throw `ERROR_CODE_X`

    expect(received).rejects.toThrow(expected)

    Expected substring: "ERROR_CODE_X"

    Received function did not throw
```

Which clearly states that it did not throw while the function does throw.

And if we change it to be an Error (`throw new Error('ERROR_CODE_X')`), then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.reject make expect to test rejected value so you can use standard expect matches here

```
async function funToTest(): Promise<number> {
  throw "ERROR_CODE_X";
}
async function funToError(): Promise<number> {
  throw new Error("ERROR_CODE_X");
}

describe("funToTest", () => {
  it("should throw `ERROR_CODE_X`", async () => {
    //await expect(() => funToTest()).rejects.toThrowErrorMatchingSnapshot();
    // ^^^ not ok: undefined in snapshot
    await expect(() => funToTest()).rejects.toMatchSnapshot();
    await expect(() => funToTest()).rejects.toEqual("ERROR_CODE_X");
  });
  it("should not throw `ERROR_CODE_X`", async () => {
    await expect(() => funToError()).rejects.toThrowErrorMatchingSnapshot();

    await expect(() => funToError()).rejects.toEqual("ERROR_CODE_X");
    //fail here: rejects return a Error
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I totally ignored the fact that we can use normal matchers when using rejects API.